# The process cannot access the file 'D:\local\IIS\Project\ProjectLog\Log1.xml' because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, xml

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\local\IIS\Project\ProjectLog\Log1.xml' because it is being used by another process.

```
167:        OldName = foldername + "\\Log.xml";
168:    }
169:    File.Copy(OldName, NewName, true);
170:    File.AppendAllText(NewName, "</root>");
171:    string FilePath = foldername + "\\Log1.xml";
```

Source File: d:\local\IIS\Project\Website\AdminPages\Viewlog.aspx.cs

How to fix this issue?

Comment: At what line exactly is it breaking?

Comment: string FilePath = foldername + "\\Log1.xml";

Comment: Why this issue occurs?

Comment: I don't think that line is breaking. If you use your debugger, what line shows the breakpoint?

Comment: Thanks for ur response. i will use debugger and let u know.

Comment: OldName = foldername + "\\Log.xml";